# nodejs tests randomly fail on CircleCI

Tags: node.js, jestjs

We are building an application using **nodejs** and writing asynchronous  tests for it using **Jest**. There is a problem we have been facing for a while now in regards to tests; sometimes tests fail on CircleCI while other times they pass. And yes, we are using **async/await** method to wait for the data to be fetched first before doing an assertion. Here is a snippet from the tests file:

```
it('should return the expected number of trips', async () => {
  const postResp = await request(app)
    .post('/api/v1/requests')
    .set('authorization', token)
    .send(mockRequest);
  const createdRequestId = postResp.body.request.id;

  const getResp = await request(app)
    .get(`/api/v1/requests/${createdRequestId}`)
    .set('authorization', token);
  expect(getResp.body.requestData.trips).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

And this is the error that was thrown by CircleCI in regards to this block of test:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'trips' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

There has to be more than this error. i.e some failed requests or the content of the response that you are getting back from the server.

What you might want to do is to log the content of getResp or getResp.body first. then check if the request you are making is returning the right results in circle ci.

You can login via ssh to circle ci so that you can debug by following this step layed out here. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ssh-access-jobs/ depending on if you are using circle ci 1 or two.

Only then can you know the cause of the error